# minishift folder mount to a VPC is not writable

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, minishift

I am using minishift 1.22 and OC tools 3.10 on Windows 10.  I used the minishift created a storage, allocated 20 MB and made it RWX (Read-Write-Many).

In my pods, I mounted this storage and mapped it to a folder.  When I deploy, it failed because the folder mounted to the PV is not writable.  If I don't mount the PV, I can deploy the pod successfully.  I changed the PV by:
sudo chmod -R o+rwx /var/lib/minishift/openshift.local.pv/pv*

Since a random user does the deployment, I also changed the folder to be owned by this random user.  That did not help.

If I use VOLUME inside the image, - VOLUME ["/etc/zookeeper/secrets"], mount to the temporary volume is fine.

What is the right way to mount and access an openshift PVC?